# Can maths be derived from physics?

Tags: mathematics

One of my friend derived AM GM inequality from thermodynamics. Are we supposed to call that a derivation? As it seems to me that it is just a way in which AM GM inequality got applied in physics.

Comment: Isn't it the way around? It all starts with logics. That is the basis for math. And math is the basis for physics.

Comment: I also think the same . And thats why i asked the question .

Comment: Math is not a basis or necessity for physics. I can describe the world around me without math. I can say the Sun is warm, yellow, hot and I can define a thermometer by looking at the expansion of a metal rod in the sun and describe all future temperatures from that. rather, I consider math a language with which to *describe* physics. And because it is so logically stringent, it is a very effective tool. But math, being a language, is thus not derived from nor deriving physics. It is a separate discipline that turned out to be helpful in *describing* physics.

Comment: As you can see, physicists don't really like this kind of question, preferring to do just do the science. There is a huge amount of expert opinion on this, ask for it on Philosophy SE. For instance Cartwright on whether physical laws are real (they are not)  http://www.oxfordscholarship.com/mobile/view/10.1093/0198247044.001.0001/acprof-9780198247043 and Tegmark's https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_universe_hypothesis

Comment: Einstein wrote 'Geometry and Experience' questioning this relationship. And Hawking on whether Goedel's theorems imply physics must remain incomplete (he thought yes). It is absolutely a question for physics and physicists.  Survey of the issue https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relationship_between_mathematics_and_physics

Answer (score 2):

Well it is really a matter of approach. Many of Math was “discovered” in try to understand physical phenomenon better. A great example is how Newton *invented* calculus for the purpose of modeling Gravitation better to develop Newton’s Shell Theorem. There are numerous other examples. So it is true that many complex physical phenomena leads to the formulation of new tools to understand them, that is Math.

Now there are also many other math theorems that only exist in The abstract world or you can say the realm of pure logic. So math can exist on by itself but Physics will always need **some** of math as math is an invaluable tool to help understand our universe better.

Comment: Leibniz, who's notation we use,  was far more important to calculus.  Anecdotally it seems much more common that maths explores a bigger field and physics the  narrow applications eg. 
imaginary numbers, Riemann geometry, topology. The influences can go to-and-fro also https://www.weforum.org/agenda/2018/05/there-s-a-weird-link-between-coffee-and-cryptocurrency Of course this gives no insight onto ontological status

Comment: Yes, ofcourse I agree on Leibniz and his vast contributions. I do believe Newton and he found out calculus independently. I brought up Newton here as his example directly relates to a physics model. It’s true that math encompasses a broader range but in my opinion just math on itself feel can surely exist and be interesting throughout history.

Comment: Then you have taken up The mathematical idealism, which comes with a host of problems including substance dualism implying Descartes' 'ghosts in the machine' and so on. You might wish to consider your other options https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_mathematics#Contemporary_schools_of_thought

Comment: I think it’s hard to believe but equally hard to disprove that all mathematical structures that can be modeled, exist. I don’t think that a ‘ghost in the machine’ arises from this. So may I ask, what do *you* believe?

Comment: I'm with Wheeler https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_physics#Wheeler.27s_.22it_from_bit.22 And maths from that